# Schema Registry container: Server died unexpectedly when launching using docker-compose

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

I have written docker-compose.yml file to create the following containers:

- Confluent-Zookeeper
- Confluent-Kafka
- Confluent-Schema Registry

I want a single docker-compose file to spun up the necessary containers, expose required ports and interconnect the dependent containers. The goal is to have 
I am using the official confluent images from Docker Hub.
My docker-compose file looks like this:

```
zookeeper:
  image: confluent/zookeeper
  container_name: confluent-zookeeper
  hostname: zookeeper
  environment:
    ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
  ports:
    - "2181:2181"

kafka:
  environment:
    KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECTION_STRING: zookeeper:2181
    KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092
  image: confluent/kafka
  container_name: confluent-kafka
  hostname: kafka
  links:
    - zookeeper
  ports:
    - "9092:9092"

schema-registry:
  image: confluent/schema-registry
  container_name: confluent-schema_registry
  environment:
    SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_CONNECTION_URL: zookeeper:2181
    SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOSTNAME: schema-registry
    SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS: http://schema-registry:8081
    SCHEMA_REGISTRY_DEBUG: 'true'
    SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: '1'
  links:
    - kafka
    - zookeeper
  ports:
    - "8081:8081"
```

Now when I run `docker-compose up`, all these containers will be created and launched. But Schema Registry container exits immediately. `docker logs` gives the following output:

```
 (io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryConfig:135)
[2017-05-17 06:06:33,415] ERROR Server died unexpectedly:  (io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryMain:51)
org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Only plaintext and SSL Kafka endpoints are supported and none are configured.
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaStore.getBrokerEndpoints(KafkaStore.java:254)
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaStore.<init>(KafkaStore.java:111)
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaSchemaRegistry.<init>(KafkaSchemaRegistry.java:136)
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryRestApplication.setupResources(SchemaRegistryRestApplication.java:53)
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryRestApplication.setupResources(SchemaRegistryRestApplication.java:37)
        at io.confluent.rest.Application.createServer(Application.java:117)
        at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryMain.main(SchemaRegistryMain.java:43)
```

I searched for this issue but nothing helped. I tried various other configurations like providing KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOSTNAME, changing SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS value, etc. but no luck.
Can anybody point out the exact configuration issue why Schema Registry container is failing?

Answer (score 1):

Those are old and deprecated docker images. Use the latest supported docker images from confluentinc https://hub.docker.com/u/confluentinc/

You can find a full compose file here - [confluentinc/cp-docker-images](https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-docker-images/blob/master/examples/cp-all-in-one/docker-compose.yml)

Comment: They work for me. You are missing the statement that SR "depends_on -zookeeper -kafka"

Comment: schema_registry:     image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:3.2.1     depends_on:       - zookeeper       - kafka     ports:       - '8081'     environment:       SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: schema_registry       SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_CONNECTION_URL: 'zookeeper:2181'

Comment: I tried these images also. But no luck!
I added `hostname: schema-registry` in docker-compose file. I landed up with new error:
`SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME is required.`
`Command [/usr/local/bin/dub ensure SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME] FAILED !`

But this is already mentioned in docker-compose file.

Comment: `links` and `depends_on` does the similar function. But I just saw that in newer version docker deprecated `links`. I'll try with `depends_on`.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the hostname (`hostname: schema-registry`) entry in the failing container. By default Docker will populate a container's `/etc/hosts` with the linked containers' aliases and names, plus the hostname of self.

Answer (score 0):

The question is old, though it might be helpful to leave a solution that worked for me. I am using docker-compose:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluent/zookeeper:3.4.6-cp1
    hostname: "zookeeper"
    networks:
      - test-net
    ports:
      - 2181:2181
    environment:
      zk_id: "1"

  kafka:
    image: confluent/kafka:0.10.0.0-cp1
    hostname: "kafka"
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    networks:
      - test-net
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: "kafka"
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: "0"
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "zookeeper:2181"

  schema-registry:
    image: confluent/schema-registry:3.0.0
    hostname: "schema-registry"
    depends_on:
      - kafka
      - zookeeper
    networks:
      - test-net
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    environment:
      SR_HOSTNAME: schema-registry
      SR_LISTENERS: http://schema-registry:8081
      SR_DEBUG: 'true'
      SR_KAFKASTORE_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: '1'
      SR_KAFKASTORE_TOPIC_SERVERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092

networks:
  test-net:
    driver: bridge`
```